# Create MySQL Replication Delay

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

Is there any way to force a replication delay using MySQL? E.g. I want a slave to be 12 hours behind a master. Anyway to make this happen?

Comment: You could have a cron job manually enable/disable replication every twelve hours, but I'm not aware of anything that would enforce a 12 hour delay. That kind of violates the whole ACID setup, as the slaves are supposed to be kept as synchronized as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Maatkit toolkit has a tool for this:

http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-slave-delay.html

Answer (score 1):

Update: MySQL 5.6 is looking at adding replication delay:

http://forge.mysql.com/worklog/task.php?id=344

**EDIT**:

Link to details on availability in 5.6.2:

http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=27133

Comment: This has been discussed since late 2005. Almost 6 years later still on the request shelf!

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL-5.6 it is possible to delay the MySQL slave deliberately. At slave you need to configure: CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_DELAY=X, where X=no of seconds you want the slave to lag behind originating master(the server at which the events are being generated). The lag is computed with respect to the time at which the originating master picked up the event for execution (not committed). Here is the documentation link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-delayed.html  You can find the complete design notes regarding this feature at http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=344